# iOS: Programmatically create labels inside scroll view created programmatically

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, uilabel, xcode5

I am developing a project in which I have created scroll view and labels inside scroll view programmatically using following code:

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 240)];

int bx=0;

for (NSString * str1 in arr1)
{
    if ([arr1 count]<=2) {
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bx, -1, scrollView.frame.size.width/[arr1 count], 100)];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else
    {
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bx, -1, 106, 100)];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",str1]];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    bx +=label.frame.size.width;
}
```

I want to create another line of labels below the above created labels using new array.and also I want to give different color to each label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood, but maybe you should try to play with  the second property of your CGRectMake which is for the Y value.